# View file structure in VS Code

Tags: structure, visual-studio-code

One of the features I use frequently in PHPStorm is the Structure window, which shows me my file structure broken down into functions, classes, variables, etc . I'm checking out VS Code, and I don't see an option for that type of window anywhere. Is there a similar window, or other way I can view the structure of my file?

Thanks.

Comment: Related issue on github: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/5605 Extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=patrys.vscode-code-outline

Comment: VSCode now ships with a default [Outline View](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_outline-view) that displays the symbol tree/file component structure of the currently active editor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up going with [Code Outline tree provider for Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=patrys.vscode-code-outline) as mentioned by @Mikhail above, and it works well.

Comment: now this extension is now unpublished from Marketplace. Can you suggest an alternative?

Comment: @KamilGareev As indicated in the answer above, this is now available by default in VS Code.

Answer (score 55):

The latest version of VS Code now has "Outline view" shipped in

From their site:

> The Outline view is out of preview and now enabled by default.

You can read more about this here:

https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_25#_outline-view

Comment: It tends to hide at the bottom of "Explorer" view.

Answer (score 4):

In the latest version of Visual Studio Code to open file structure which is called *Outline* in VS click:

1. *View*
2. Then *Open View...*
3. And select *Outline*